# How to include -std=c++11 and -lpthread in makefile?

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, g++, pthreads

I tried the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109453/location-of-lpthread-in-c-makefile), but it's for GCC and didn't help anyways.

I want to `#include <thread>` in a file, so I have a make file as the following:

```
OBJS    = clitest.o Sources/NClient.o
CC      = g++
DEBUG   = -g
CFLAGS  = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS  = -Wall $(DEBUG)

clitest: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o clitest
```

Where should I include `-std=c++11` and `-lpthread` in this?
I've tried just about every combination I can, but I continue to get this error when I run `make`:

`/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.`

I believe this is the command it's running?

```
[jaska@localhost NClient]make
g++    -c -o clitest.o clitest.cpp
```

Here's the source code file, too:

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>

void task(std::string msg){
    std::cout << msg << '\n';
}

...
...

std::thread t1(task, "message");
client->create();
t1.join();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your makefile doesn't have an explicit rule for compiling the objects in `$(OBJS)` so that means the implicit rule will be used, which is what produces this command:

```
g++    -c -o clitest.o clitest.cpp
```

The implicit rule for turning a `.cpp` file into a `.o` file is approximately:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

so to add options that affect that rule you should add them to the `CXXFLAGS` variable (`CFLAGS` is conventionally used for compiling C files, and `CC` is the C compiler, the conventional variable for the C++ compiler is `CXX`).

The `-lpthread` option is a linker option, so need to be given during linking. You have defined your own rule for linking, so you should either add `-lpthread` to that recipe or add it to the `LFLAGS` variable.

N.B. using `-Wall` and `-g` during linking is useless, they have no effect.

N.B. adding `-c` to the `CFLAGS` is wrong, the implicit rules for compiling `.c` files already include `-c`, just as the implicit one for C++ files includes `-c`. This doesn't cause any problems because the `CFLAGS` variable is not used by your makefile, or by the implicit rule for compiling `.cpp` files.

N.B. instead of linking to `-lpthread` you should compile **and** link with `-pthread`

N.B. the implicit rule for linking, and makefile convention, is to use the variable `LDFLAGS` for linker options, and `LIBS` for libraries such as `-lpthread`, so I would rewrite your makefile as:

```
OBJS    = clitest.o Sources/NClient.o
CXX     = g++
DEBUG   = -g
CXXFLAGS  = -Wall $(DEBUG) -std=c++11 -pthread
LDFLAGS = -pthread

clitest: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

This still relies on the implicit rule for turning the `.cpp` files into `.o` files, but now that implicit rule will pick up the right options from the `CXXFLAGS` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Add to `CFLAGS` and `LFLAGS`

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -c $(DEBUG) -std=c++11 -pthread
LFLAGS  = -Wall $(DEBUG) -std=c++11 -pthread
```

that should be enough.

For implicit rules also overwrite the `CXXFLAGS` variable

```
CXXFLAGS  = -Wall -c $(DEBUG) -std=c++11 -pthread
```

As you see from your command line output

> ```
> [jaska@localhost NClient]make
> g++    -c -o clitest.o clitest.cpp
> ```

the other flags from `CFLAGS` also weren't used for compiling.

Comment: It's still making the same error - I added some relevant code to the question, though.

Comment: @jaska Seems you don't override the `%o: %.cpp` rule in your makefile. Put the same options to `CXXFLAGS` as well please.

Answer (score 1):

They are effectively command line parameters to gcc/g++ or ld, the linker. So they must be passed as additions to CFLAGS and LFLAGS (or possibly as CXXFLAGS, CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS depending on how the Makefile functions). Your example does not show you passing CFLAGS to the C++ compiler though, so that is also problematic. Pass it explicitly or set the CXXFLAGS for your C++ compiler (C is not C++).

I would suggest you resolve your problem initially on the command line and then when it works move on to the Makefile. Effectively you're trying to get Make to create the line:

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -pthread clitest.o Sources/NCLient.o -o clitest
```

Comment: I thought so, too, but it was working fine without the `-pthread` etc.

Comment: The correct spelling of the option is `-std` not `--std`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Whoops. Thanks!